# Show and hide from RadioButton - Javascript

Tags: javascript, radio-button, arcgis, if-statement

I use this code in HTML for the RadioButton:

```
<fieldset>
  <div class="someclass">
  <span>Tekeningen: </span>
    <label for="ValSR2">UIT:</label>
  <input dojoType="dijit.form.RadioButton" id="valSR2" name="group3" checked="checked" value="Show" onchange='Tekeningen(this);' value="Show" type="radio" />
    <label for="ValSlope2">AAN:</label>
 <input dojoType="dijit.form.RadioButton" id="valSlope2" name="group3" value="Hide" onchange='Tekeningen(this);' type="radio"/>
 </div>
</fieldset>
```

And this as function:

```
function Tekeningen(evt){
        dojo.connect(map, "onLoad", mapLoadHandler);
        var tekeningen = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("https://gis.strukton.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Tekeningen_Data/MapServer", { id: "Tekeningen", "visible":true});

                if(evt.value === "Hide"){
                    alert("removelayer");



//var tek = map.getLayer("Tekeningen");
            //      tek.hide();
            map.removeLayer(tekeningen);

                }
          else if(evt.value === "Show"){        
                            //  map.removeLayer(tekeningen);        
                                        alert("addlayer");

                                        map.addLayer(tekeningen);



          }
      }
```

But when i turn it on i get both the alerts, and when i turn it off also.
Does anyone know what im doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I am searching what i am doing wrong in the part of value="hide" and why the function cant see that value.."

Answer (score 0):

I have tried an simplified function in jsFiddle and it works right for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/UFDDR/

```
function Tekeningen(evt){
    if(evt.value === "Hide"){
        alert("removelayer");
    }
    else if(evt.value === "Show"){        
        alert("addlayer");
    }
}
```